# Makefile "no such file or directory. stop" with cygwin64 on windows

Tags: android, makefile, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I am trying to compile a certain android kernel module on my windows 10 pc using Android NDK.

I tried to build it using the following Makefile:

```
VERSION = 2
PATCHLEVEL = 6
SUBLEVEL = 29
EXTRAVERSION =

obj-m := test.o

PWD := $(shell pwd)

default:
    $(MAKE) ARCH=arm64 CROSS_COMPILE=/home/AndroidNDK/android-ndk-r21d/toolchains/aarch64-linux- android-4.9/bin/aarch64-linux-android- -C  $(KERNEL_DIR) SUBDIRS=$(PWD) modules
clean:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KERNEL_PATH) SUBDIRS=$(PWD) clean
```

But keep getting this error:

```
make ARCH=arm64 CROSS_COMPILE=/home/AndroidNDK/android-ndk-r21d/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/bin/aarch64-linux-android- -C   SUBDIRS=/cygdrive/c/Project  modules
make[1]: *** SUBDIRS=/cygdrive/c/Project: No such file or directory.  Stop.
make: *** [Makefile:11: default] Error 2
```

- I took the Makefile from github and changed it a little.
- The module source file is called test.c

Any Idea why I get this error?

Answer (score 0):

It's quite obvious why you get that error.  Look at the command that make is running:

```
make ARCH=arm64 CROSS_COMPILE=... -C   SUBDIRS=/cygdrive/c/Project  modules
```

Notice how the string `SUBDIRS=/cygdrive/c/Project` comes after the `-C` option.  What is the `-C` option?  Check the [GNU make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Options-Summary.html) to discover it provides a directory that make is supposed to change to before starting.

So, you're telling make "change to directory named `SUBDIRS=/cygdrive/c/Project`" and of course that directory doesn't exist, so you get that error.

So why is your command line like that?  Look at the rule you wrote:

```
default:
        $(MAKE) ARCH=arm64 CROSS_COMPILE=... -C  $(KERNEL_DIR) SUBDIRS=$(PWD) modules
```

So, after the `-C` is supposed to be the value of the variable `KERNEL_DIR`.

However, in your makefile you have not defined the variable `KERNEL_DIR`, so when make expands it it expands to the empty string.

Comment: Besides that it should be _M_ rather than _SUBDIRS_.